# Unable to Update Model from Database using EF 6 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

Right click on the EF Model Designer surface and choose Update Model from Database.
[image: Update Model from Database]

In the dialog box that pops up, you should be able to browse the database, and select objects to add.  But in this case, nothing can be selected:
[image: Selecting database objects to add]

Removing the Connection String from the App.Config and allowing the Designer to re-add it did not resolve the issue.

The credentials used in the Connection String when copied and pasted in SSMS.

The database can be browsed from the VS Server Explorer window.

Creating a new blank EF project and repeating from there works fine.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of 2 problems exist, the Model already has the Tables/SP/View you are looking for or the Login does not have the Authority the access those Tables/SP/View.

Comment: In my case I needed to open ssms and run "grant exec on [proc name] to [user]"  for the user in EF's connection string.

Answer (score 0):

One of the factor unable to select any checkbox in `Update Wizard` is you don't have any updates in your database, therefore entity framework doesn't allow you to select.

If your scenario is not the factor above, you may try the method I listed below:

I had this issue too and I noticed that I didn't grant the `db_owner` under `Database role membership` for my database (eg 22Aug_M) in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**.

After I checked it and it works as normal.

[image: Example: Db Role settting in SSMS]